# Lipschitz constant of $\|Ax-b\|_2^2$ and $A^T(Ax-b)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality, optimization, lipschitz-functions

The Lipschitz constant $L$ of a function $f$ is defined as follows

$$\| f(y) - f(x) \|_2 \leq L \|y-x\|_2$$

I want to find the Lipschitz constants for the following functions:

$$f_1(x) = \|Ax-b\|_2^2$$

$$f_2(x) = A^T (Ax-b)$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, b\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

Any help?

Comment: What would be the Lipschitz constant of the function $x \mapsto (ax-b)^2$? Note that $f_2 = 2 D f_1$. Why would you set the derivative to zero????

Comment: Ok, the derivative-thing was a very stupid idea. What is $D$?

Comment: The derivative.

Comment: Oh yes, I see...

Comment: For the Lipschitz constant of the function $f_3(x) = (ax-b)^2$ I started by $||a^2 x_1^2 - 2ax_1 + b^2 - a^2 x_2^2 + 2ax_2 - b^2||_2 <= L ||x_2 - x_1||_2 \Leftrightarrow ||a^2(x_1^2-x_2^2) - 2a(x_1-x_2)||_2 <= L ||x_2 - x_1||_2 $ but further I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, a Lipschitz function can have at most linear growth at infinity: $\|f(x)\|=O(\|x\|)$ as $\|x\|\to\infty$. Since $f_1$ grows quadratically, it is not a Lipschitz function.

For $f_2$, note that
$$\|f_2(x)-f_2(y)\| = \|A^TA(x-y)\| \le \|A^TA\| \|x-y\|$$
and the inequality is sharp by the definition of the operator norm. Thus, the Lipschitz constant of $f_2$ is $\|A^TA\|$ (which further simplifies to $\|A\|^2$, [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213653/show-that-norm-of-matrix-a-is-given-by-the-square-root-of-the-largest-eigenval)).