# Do we have $\|\Sigma v\|_{\infty}\ge \gamma\|v\|_{\infty}?$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, statistics

For a covariance matrix $\Sigma\in R^{d\times d}$, if for a vector $v\in R^d$ we have
$$
\|\Sigma^{1/2}v\|_{\infty}\ge \gamma\|v\|_{\infty}
$$
for a constant $\gamma>0$. Can we have a similar lower bound for $\|\Sigma v\|_{\infty}$? For example, $\|\Sigma v\|_{\infty}\ge \gamma\|v\|_{\infty}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\|\Sigma v\|_\infty =  \|\Sigma^\frac12(\Sigma^\frac12v)\|_\infty\geq \gamma\|\Sigma^\frac12v\|_\infty\geq\dots
$$

Comment: Thanks! How about the converse statement? If we have $\|\Sigma v\|_{\infty}\ge \gamma \|v\|_{\infty}$, is there some constants such that $\|\Sigma ^{1/2} v\|_{\infty}\ge C\|v\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: @qqeisit The best $gamma$ is called the operator/matrix norm of $\Sigma^\frac12$, so essentially your question is about how operator norms behave with the square root. For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213653/show-that-norm-of-matrix-a-is-given-by-the-square-root-of-the-largest-eigenval

Comment: So the converse statement is true?